Access to XMLHttpRequest at has been blocked by CORS policy It does not have HTTP ok status
I have an application which is developed in 4.8 framework and another application .NET 8.0. The one in 4.8 is where I am developing the API's and consuming in the other project. I added this in web.config but no luck. Initially I got it when I am using a GET call but after adding this it was good. But the same is not working for POST call so can some one let me know what changes I need to do
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
</customHeaders>

Here is my controller
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
   [Route("api/process-all-ids")]
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessAllIds([FromBody] List<int> ids)
   {
   }
}


No idea why you decided to omit half the error message but this should answer your question: ASP.NET MVC Preflight (OPTIONS) requests handling

I tried that but no luck

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44344/api/PendingApply' from origin 'https://localhost:44339' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:44339/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

This is what I tried and it worked removed the web.config settings related to CORS and added the following
Removed this from config
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
</customHeaders>

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originHeader = Request.Headers["Origin"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(originHeader))
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
        Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
        Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");

        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}

